# aggregate in R by permutations of column values

Tags: r, aggregate

**Background:** I'm working with origin-destination data. I would like to calculate the proportional flow between each pair of cities. However, I'm finding it difficult to aggregate data by each pair of cities since the pairs involve permutations of column entries. I can do it by brute force using lots of for loops and conditionals, but this takes far too long to compute.

**Specifically** 
Given a matrix of the following form:

```
Origin     Destination    Flow   
a          b              f1  
b          a              f2    
c          d              f3    
d          c              f4
```

I would like to calculate the aggregation

```
Pair      Flow
a,b       f1+f2
c,d       f3+f4
```

I tried to do this by reversing the origin-destination columns, appending to the original data set, aggregating by the origin and destination columns, using xtabs to create a symmetric matrix, and then just taking the upper triangle. However, this doesn't see to be working properly.

Comment: Is `Flow` a numeric/integer column in real life?

Comment: Yes, it is a integer counting the number of people commuting between pairs of towns.

Comment: or `aggregate(dd$Flow, list(apply(dd[1:2], 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = ','))), paste, collapse = '+')`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df$pair <- ifelse(df$Destination < df$Origin,
                  paste(df$Destination, df$Origin, sep = ','),
                  paste(df$Origin, df$Destination, sep = ','))

df %>% group_by(pair) %>% summarise(Flow = paste(Flow, collapse = ' + '))

Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

   pair    Flow
  (chr)   (chr)
1   a,b f1 + f2
2   c,d f3 + f4
```

The Flow column is obviously paste using character vectors since that is what you gave. You can modify to `sum(Flow)` if you have numeric values.

EDITED: Sorry, earlier, I was summing wrong column. Fixed.

Comment: A common alternative to `ifelse(x < y, paste(x,y), paste(y,x))` is `paste(pmin(x,y), pmax(x,y))`.

Comment: Oh yeah....I was looking at those but and ignored thinking character strings. But, that would still work. Excellent comment.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot!